# How do I get EyeTV to work on my 2007 iMac?

Tags: macos

I'm running a 2007 24" iMac, and recently installed OS X Lion.  I am trying to use the EyeTV software for my Elgato TV tuner.  When I run the program, Console logs messages of the form:

```
automountd[14168]: parse_entry: bad key in map auto_home: EyeTV Archive
```

and the program crashes.  I have a vague understanding of what autofs is, but I have no idea why it is being invoked.  I looked up Apple's autofs source code and it seems that "EyeTV Archive" is being passed in as a key to something, somewhere (like I said, I know know much about autofs).  Can somebody help, please?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you have an unmounted volume set in the EyeTV settings under *Recording* / *"EyeTV Archive" Location*.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting any Library folders used by EyeTV before running the app. This has solved different issues that I have had with EyeTV in the past. Hope this helps.